# Don't run GitHub Actions workflow if a specific set of files are changed

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two workflows, `wA` and `wB`, corresponding to builds of two Docker images `A` and `B`. Image `B` has a base of image `A`, and thus has a direct dependency. `wB` is triggered by any changes in `B` using a `paths` filter, but is also triggered by the execution of `wA` through a `workflow_run` trigger—we want to rebuild `B` when its base image changes.

If a push changes files in both `A` and `B`, we run into the situation where both `wA` and `wB` are immediately queued, then `wB` is run *again* after the conclusion of `wA`. This isn't necessarily a dealbreaker, but that first run of `wB` is unnecessary since *we know* that it will be triggered on the conclusion of `wA` and will simply be superseded, and this can pose an issue for our longer-running builds. (I suppose that such a dependency would fail to trigger `wB` on the failure of `wA` when it really still could be built, but I consider that perfectly fine.)

If a push only changes files in `B`, we still want `wB` to run.

Does there exist a way to run a workflow only if a specific path filter *does not* match, e.g. "run `wB` only if (but not if and only if) there are no changes in `A`"? It doesn't seem like setting up a negative filter on `paths` is adequate here, as GitHub's documentation notes:

> When all the path names match patterns in `paths-ignore`, the workflow will not run. If any path names do not match patterns in `paths-ignore`, even if some path names match the patterns, the workflow will run.

As such, ignoring changes in `A` in `wB`'s paths filter wouldn't have any effect if changes exist in `B`.

If not, might there be a better way to encode this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this kind of logic

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'templates/**'
      - 'package.json'
      - 'FileB'
```

But instead of `paths` you can use `paths-ignore`.

Plus add some concurrency grouping:

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}_your_run_name
  cancel-in-progress: true
```